# Mapping a key for calling the recent apps list

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, google-now, recents-screen, home-button

I have a new Nubia phone. After I installed Google Now, it overwrote the middle key long tap so that it shows the Now screen but I became unable to switch between recent apps. Moreover, the apps like Switchr cannot show recent apps since Android 5.0. How can I remap the button or call the recent apps screen any other way?

Comment: Not sure which one covers explicitly that, but be welcome to take a look at my list for apps to [Edit Key Settings](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_settings#group_546).

Comment: Do you not have the setting Buttons under Settings app? Is the device rooted?

Comment: @Firelord not rooted; cannot find settings for that. Should I root?

Comment: Yes, if you root you can easily change mapping of long-press of keys using Xposed Additions or Gravitybox [LP] app. Both of them requires Xposed Framework installed too. It means that you would need a custom recovery installed too.